# Measuring information content of a random variable in Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification

I'm trying to improve accuracy in a Naive Bayes classifier that uses a bunch of features.  I have a hunch that removing some features may actually improve performance.  My reasoning is for a particular feature the estimated PDFs across the classes may be different slightly because of the limited amount of learning data, not because they really are different.  For example if a feature accross 2 classes had the same histogram except for some noise

```
|                      |
|||                  |||    
|||||||_ noise _|||||||| p(x1 | C1), or H1(x)

|                      |
|||                  |||
||||||||________|||||||| p(x1 | C2), or H2(x)
```

I'm already aware that when modelling p(x1 | C1) I could have chosen a larger bin-width to smooth out the noise, but let's say this was an "optimal" bandwidth in the example above.    I want to identify these kinds of cases and remove the feature.

I looked at was Kullback–Leibler divergence.  But, I can't see how to compute it because $KL(H2 || H1) = \sum H_2(i) log( \frac{H_2(i)}{H_1(i)}) $ is not defined for example histograms above because of the zeroes in one case where H2(x) is not zero.  Or vise versa for KL(H1||H2).

Any suggestions, thoughts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different smoothing techniques you can apply to your data to sidestep the 0-observation case you are explaining here.

In fact, this page [here](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~elhadad/nlp09/KL.html) describes how to handle your exact case, ie. "probability 0" events when calculating the KL divergence using "absolute discounting".

[This PDF](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~wcmac/papers/20050421-smoothing-tutorial.pdf) enumerates a number of other smoothing methods you might consider in the NLP context, as well.

Comment: Thanks.  My features aren't words but a set of real numbers for each feature.  But, I think I can adapt some of these techniques.